# How to get last three sale count days and rest of the day sale count?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sales data set for three months. I need to get the last three-day sales count and the rest day sale count. I tried the below code. but I need to change the last three-day count manually. if want to get April month, then I need to change this "x.Date.dt.day <= 27". plz give a solution to get the last three day and rest day sales count in each month.

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
print(df)
#    Device_num       Date sale_type
# 0        2344 2020-03-01        BP
# 1        2344 2020-03-12        BP
# 2        2344 2020-03-15        BP
# 3        2344 2020-03-20        BP
# 4        2344 2020-03-28        BP
# 5        3455 2020-03-10  Retailer
# 6        3455 2020-03-15  Retailer
# 7        3455 2020-03-31  Retailer


out = df.groupby(["Device_num", "sale_type", pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq="m")]).apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({"Device_num":  x.name[0],
                         "sale_type": x.name[1],
                         "1st_27dayssale": (x.Date.dt.day <= 27).sum(),
                         "Tot_sale": len(x),
                         "last4dayscount" : (x.Date.dt.day > 27).sum()})) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)
#    Device_num sale_type  1st_27dayssale  Tot_sale  last4dayscount
# 0        2344        BP               4         5               1
# 1        3455  Retailer               2         3               1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column with how many days are left until the end of the month (using `dt.daysinmonth` and `dt.day`), then convert it to `last` if it's less than 4, otherwise `first`, group by that column and calculate counts:

```
df['days_until_month_end'] = df['Date'].dt.daysinmonth - df['Date'].dt.day
df['group'] = np.where(df['days_until_month_end'] < 4, 'last', 'first')

z = df.groupby(['Device_num', 'sale_type', 'group']).size().unstack('group')
z['total'] = z.sum(1)
z
```

Output:

```
group                 first  last  total
Device_num sale_type                    
2344       BP             4     1      5
3455       Retailer       2     1      3
```